# Dates fetched using ajax but not highlighted in Jquery UI datepicker, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery datepicker to highlight specific dates. Dates are being fetched from the database in PHP and MySQL. Dates will be fetched depending on the selected value in the select tag. The dates are successfully fetched and shown in the console.

If I fetch all the dates in the script directly then it shows the highlighted dates. But when I use select tag and send the selected value through ajax then it doesn't.

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // An array of dates
        var eventDates = {};

        $("#select").on("change", function() {
            var truck = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/vehicledate.php',
                type: "POST",
                /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
                data: {
                    val: truck
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            // datepicker
            $('#start').datepicker({

                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var highlight = eventDates[date];
                    if (highlight) {
                        return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
                    } else {
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Jquery to fetch all dates

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        // An array of dates
        var eventDates = {};

        <?php        

            $sql = "SELECT * from `ut_trips` WHERE `deisel` > 0";

            $result = $connect->query($sql);   

            while( $final=$result->fetch_assoc() ) 
            {

            ?>

            eventDates[new Date('<?php 
            $orgDate = date($final['date']);
            $date = str_replace('-"', '/', $orgDate);  
            $newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));  
            echo $newDate   ?>')] = new Date(
            '<?php $orgDate =date($final['date']); 
            $date = str_replace('-"', '/', $orgDate);  
            $newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));  
            echo $newDate  
            ?>'
            );

            <?php

            }

            ?>

            // datepicker
            $('#start').datepicker({

                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var highlight = eventDates[date];
                    if (highlight) {
                        return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
                    } else {
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

ajax PHP file

```
<?php

include("../partials/connect.php");

$v = $_POST['val'];

$sql = "SELECT * from `table` WHERE `value1` > 0 AND `value2` = '".$v."'";

$result = $connect->query($sql);   

while( $final=$result->fetch_assoc() ) 
{

?>

eventDates[new Date('<?php 
$orgDate = date($final['date']);
$date = str_replace('-"', '/', $orgDate);  
$newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));  
echo $newDate   ?>')] = new Date(
'<?php $orgDate =date($final['date']); 
$date = str_replace('-"', '/', $orgDate);  
$newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));  
echo $newDate  
?>'
);

<?php

}

?>
```

console output

```
eventDates[new Date('2021/11/10')] = new Date(
'2021/11/10'
);


eventDates[new Date('2021/11/12')] = new Date(
'2021/11/12'
);


eventDates[new Date('2021/11/13')] = new Date(
'2021/11/13'
);
```

**Update:**

echo out the date in jason format

```
echo jason_encode($newDate);
```

Jquery

```
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
 }
```

using dataType: "json" outputs nothing in console and if I comment It out it will output `eventDates[new Date('2021\/11\/12')] = new Date( '2021\/11\/12' );` in colsole.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the response to the AJAX call, except logging it to the console. It never goes anywhere near your datepicker. The output stays in `data`, as a string. Get your PHP to output _data_ (e.g. in JSON format) instead of _code_, so you can then pass the data to the datepicker from your "success" function. It's important to remember that AJAX requests don't directly cause your web page to be updated, they simply receive the response back into a JS variable, and it's then up to you to write some JS code to process that response, and use it however you want to.

Comment: @ADyson So, I defined the ```dataType: "json"``` and echo out the dates as ```json_encode($newDate)``` in PHP file. but it outputs nothing in the console either. and what should I use instead of concole.log in success to pass the data.

Comment: Please be warned that the query from your AJAX file is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase The problem has been solved. it was an ajax problem to pass the dates to datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can see to update the display *after* the calendar has already been rendered is to use [the `refresh` method](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh).  How to highlight new dates though?  You could do that by adding the new dates to your existing set of `eventDates`, and then simply refreshing the whole calendar - `beforeShowDay` will process the new, updated set of `eventDates`, and your new dates will be higlighted.

See the snippet below for a working example.

But firstly, **your code is open to SQL injection!** Fix this first, immediately, eg [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) It should be pretty simple, eg maybe something like this:

```
include("../partials/connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * from `table` WHERE `value1` > 0 AND `value2` = ?";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);   
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['val']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // ... etc, some tips below
```

OK, on to the Javascript.  Some notes and suggestions:

1. Currently you are initialising the datepicker inside the select change handler.  This means that every time the select is changed, you re-initialise the datepicker.  You shouldn't do that - initialise it once, independent of any user interaction.
2. I am not sure I understand why you have structured `eventDates` that way.  At least according to the code/requirements you've shown here, it would be far simpler as a simple array, something like:

   ```
   // An array of dates
   var eventDates = [
       "2021/12/01",
       "2021/12/02",
       "2021/12/03",
   ];
   ```

   I've gone with this for my demo code in the snippet below.
3. In your AJAX call, you're passing a value with `val: selectvalue` - but `selectvalue` does not seem to be defined anywhere.  You did already find the selected value though - `truck`.  So that's the value you want to send.
4. [Convention is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) that POST is for *changing* data (eg making a purchase, updating a record), while GET is for *reading* data.  You're just loading some date data, so that really should be a GET.  I'd suggest sticking with convention and updating your back end to respond to GET instead of POST.
5. Once you receive your new dates from the AJAX call, <s>you need to add them to the existing set of `eventDates`.  If `eventDates` is a simple array as suggested above, that's easy (at least if you [search SO for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating)!): `eventDates.push(...newDates);`.</s>. **Update** from discussion in comments, new dates should actually replace existing dates completely: `eventDates = newDates;`
6. And finally, refresh the whole calendar: `$('#start').datepicker("refresh");`

Putting it all together, here is a working demo:

```js
$(function() {
    // An array of dates - dummy data for demo
    var eventDates = [
        "2021/12/01",
        "2021/12/02",
        "2021/12/03",
    ];

    // Initialise datepicker - once
    $('#start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            // date is a JS date, we want to compare it to the dates
            // in eventDates, so we need to format it.  Datepicker has
            // a handy utility for formatting dates, see
            // https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate
            var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);

            // Easy way to check if a value is in an array
            if (eventDates.indexOf(formatted) === -1) {
                return [true, '', ''];
            } else {
                return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
            }
        }
    });

    $("#select").on("change", function() {
        // Can't do AJAX here, but we can write the success method, and 
        // just use a hard-coded set of results.  Say your AJAX returns
        // a new set of dates, as an array:
        var data = [
            "2021/12/24",
            "2021/12/25",
            "2021/12/26",
        ];
        
        // To merge existing dates with new dates
        // eventDates.push(...data);

        // To show only new dates:
        eventDates = data;

        // So new eventDates is updated with the new dates, we want
        // to reresh the whole calendar.
        $('#start').datepicker("refresh");
        
        // Done!  To be clear, your AJAX success would look like this:
        // success: function(data) {
        //    eventDates.push(...data);
        //    $('#start').datepicker("refresh");
        // }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.event {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="start" type="text">

<select id="select">
    <option>Change me</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

As to your PHP, assuming you have fixed the SQL injection problems described earlier, you need to return a JSON array.  I can't really work out what your existing code is doing - what format is `$final['date']`?  To demostrate how to create and return your array, I'll just assume it is actually a date in the right format.  Adjust as necessary.

```
// Define the empty array we will return.
$eventDates = [];

// Iterate over your query results ...
while ($final = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // ... adding each date to the array, let's say $final['date'] is 
    // formatted like 2021/12/25
    $eventDates[] = $final['date'];
}

// We want to return JSON, so jQuery can read it
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($eventDates);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and It works but I don't want to append the new dates with the old ones. As I select the value from the select tag, the date should be replaced with a new one. how can I do that?

Comment: "*the date should be replaced with a new one*" - what date should be replaced?  And what does "replaced" mean, exactly?

Comment: Currently, When I select the value it returns the date in datepicker. But when I select another value then the dates are being shown in datepicker but also with the previous dates fetched for the previously selected value. What I am trying is to fetch and show dates only for the selected value.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that after a new date is selected, whatever is returned from the AJAX should be displayed as highlighted on the calendar, and nothing else?  In that case instead of combining the 2 `eventDates` arrays, you would just replace it with the new dates, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240063/discussion-between-tru-shar-and-dont-panic).